# Raspberry Pi to Arduino GPIO wire length

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I want to connect a Raspberry Pi 3 to an Arduino via there IO pins so the Pi can send control commands to the Arduino.

The distance between the two devices is around 10 feet (around 3 meters), is this viable using the IO port or is the gap too long?  I haven't been able to find the specific specifications for this when I searched.

Thank you in advance xx

Comment: Please post your question at the [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) group. This group is only software.

Answer (score 1):

The length of the wires is not an issue, but be careful because the GPIO pins of the Pi are 3.3V and the pins of the Arduino are 5V. So be sure to use a level converter between the Pi and the Arduino or you will probably fry your Raspberry.

If you want to send the commands over Serial you also have to connect the RX of the Pi to the TX of the Arduino and vice versa.